# how to implement efficiently a symmetric padding of a matrix in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, padding

I want to replicate a numpy function named [pad](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).
It supports some variants of the padding.

I am interested in symmetric padding of a 2D array (Matrix) without any dependency.
Namely implement as a function.

For the `replicate` mode I created:

```
function padimagereplicate(input, pad)
    # Nearest Neighbor (Replicate)
    
    m, n = size(input)
    
    i = clamp.((1 - input[1]):(m + input[1]), 1, m)
    j = clamp.((1 - input[2]):(n + input[2]), 1, n)
    
    return input[i, j]
end
```

Hot to implement efficiently the `symmetric` mode?

Comment: Your example is wrong i think. You probably meant to use `pad[1]` and `pad[2]` instead of `input` for `i` and `j`.

Comment: If you want this to be efficient, you should avoid creating index arrays. Instead, allocate a non-initialized matrix, using eg `similar`, and then fill it in a nested loop. That way you only allocate a single array, and no unnecessary temporaries.

Comment: @DNF, Care to share such code as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

One can follow your idea, and generate indices for the left/right top/bottom

Very easy if we make the assumption that the padding is less than the entire image (not necessarily true, but probably OK in most use cases)

```
function padimagesymmetric_simple(input, pad)
    # Only supports padding that is smaller than the image size.

    m, n = size(input)
    x, y = pad

    left = x:-1:1
    right = m:-1:x

    top = y:-1:1
    bottom = n:-1:x

    i = vcat(left, 1:m, right)
    j = vcat(top, 1:n, bottom)
    
    return input[i, j]
end
```

The assumption allows us to make a very simple implementation.

To handle arbitrary large padding one could use the idea of generating the "sawtooth" indexing required, then slice it off at the desired padding.

```
function padimagesymmetric(input, pad)
    m, n = size(input)
    x, y = pad

    m_tooth = vcat(1:m, m:-1:1)
    n_tooth = vcat(1:m, m:-1:1)

    m_saw = repeat(m_tooth, ceil(Int, x / length(m_tooth)))
    n_saw = repeat(n_tooth, ceil(Int, y / length(n_tooth)))

    left   = m_saw[end-x+1:end]
    right  = m_saw[1:x-1]

    top    = n_saw[end-y+1:end]
    bottom = n_saw[1:y-1]

    i = vcat(left, 1:m, right)
    j = vcat(top, 1:n, bottom)
    
    return input[i, j]
end
```

Comment: This solution creates massive amounts of temporary arrays. I suggest trying a nested loop instead.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer with code.

Comment: I cannot, since I am on holiday with no computer, just a phone. Therefore I suggest improvements to those who can.

Answer (score 1):

[ArrayPadding.jl](https://github.com/paulxshen/ArrayPadding.jl) pad function has what you need. There's also a pad function in Images.jl

Comment: I can't seem to find it. Link?

Comment: Added link - new pkg

Comment: It's generally helpful to include a simple code example of what the method usage looks like in your answer. That helps in case the link target ever moves.